# Proving pairwise independence and mutually independent

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, dice, independence

I have this problem that states:

> $A = \{\text{red die is}~3, 4,~\text{or}~5\}$
>
> $B = \{\text{blue die is}~1~\text{or}~2\}$
>
> $C = \{\text{sum is}~7\}$
>
> Both the red and blue die are under equally likely probability.

I need help finding if they are pairwise independent and if they are mutually independent. The problem is I don't quite fully understand what those two terms mean. I read the definition and examples on Wikipedia but there's so much terminology on there that makes no sense to me.

From my understanding, they are not pairwise independent because if you do $A \cap B \cap C$, $A$ doesn't have any intersection with $B$. They do intersect with $C$ if you roll a 5 on the red die and a 2 on the blue die. But they don't all share something.

For mutual independence, I can't find any definition that makes sense to me.

As you can see I'm not that great at Discrete Mathematics, so if you can explain in easy terms it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are independent because the red and blue dice are separate dice.  (If one embedded magnets in them and threw them next to each other one could question such things, but it is conventional in phrasing math problems like this to construe that as meaning they will be independent.)

Now consider $\Pr(C \mid A\ \&\ B)$ and $\Pr(C)$.  If these are equal then $C$ is independent of $[A\ \&\ B]$ but that does not mean that $C$ is independent of $A$, nor that $C$ is independent of $B$. What is the conditional distribution of the outcomes given by the red and blue dice given the event $[A\ \&\ B]$?  Given that event, six outcomes are equally probable:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
& 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline 1 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 \\
2 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6
\end{array}
$$
In only one of these outcomes, the sum is $7$; therefore $\Pr(C\mid A\ \&\ B) = 1/6$.

What is the marginal (i.e. unconditional) probability of $C$?  It is
\begin{align}
& \Pr\Big( \Big[ 1\ \&\ 6\Big] \text{ or } \Big[ 2\ \&\ 5\Big] \text{ or }  \Big[ 3\ \&\ 4\Big] \text{ or }  \Big[ 4\ \&\ 3\Big] \text{ or }  \Big[ 5\ \&\ 2\Big] \text{ or }  \Big[ 6\ \&\ 1\Big] \text{ or }   \Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {36} + \frac 1 {36} + \frac 1 {36} + \frac 1 {36} + \frac 1 {36} + \frac 1 {36} = \frac 1 6. 
\end{align}
Hence we have $\Pr(C) = \Pr(C\mid A\ \&\ B)$, so $C$ is independent of $[A\ \&\ B]$.

Is $C$ independent of $A$?  It is if $\Pr(C\mid A) = 1/6$; otherwise it's not.

\begin{align}
& \Pr(C\mid A) = \Pr(\text{sum is 7} \mid \text{red is 3, 4, or 5} ) = \frac{\Pr(\text{sum is 7 and $A$ is 3, 4, or 5})}{\Pr(\text{red is 3, 4, or 5})} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{1/36 + 1/36 + 1/36}{1/2} = \frac 1 6.
\end{align}
Therefore $A$ and $C$ are independent.

Similarly
\begin{align}
& \Pr(C\mid B) = \Pr(\text{sum is 7} \mid \text{blue is 1 or 2} ) = \frac{\Pr(\text{sum is 7 and blue is 1 or 2})}{\Pr(\text{blue is 1 or 2})} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{1/36+1/36}{1/3} = \frac 1 6. 
\end{align}
Therefore $B$ and $C$ are independent.

Thus $A$, $B$, and $C$ are pairwise independent.

Now
\begin{align}
\Pr(A\ \&\ B\ \&\ C) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C\mid A\ \&\ B) = \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 1 3 \cdot\frac 1 6 = \frac 1 {36} = \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)
\end{align}
and so the three are mutually independent.

Comment: I'm a little lost on the marginal probability of C. Also, how come you divide when checking for independence for P(C | A) and P(C | B)? Is that a general rule? If the last outcome was not 1/36 but like 2/36, they would not be mutually independent? EDIT: When you write `&`, do you mean intersection?

Comment: What is a general rule is that $\displaystyle \Pr(C\mid A) = \frac{\Pr(C\ \&\ A)}{\Pr(A)}$. The ampersand means both events, $A$ and $C$, occur, i.e. the outcome is in their intersection. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks! While I understand the reasoning behind everything you did, can you give me a simple definition of pairwise and mutually independent? From what I gather, the events can be pairwise independent as long as `P(A & B & C)` equal the same probability. For mutually independence, it is true if they equal 1 over the total possibilities. Am I correct to say that?

Comment: Three events $A,B,C$ are mutually independent if $\Pr(A\ \&\ B\ \&\ C) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)$.  _Two_ events $A,B$ are independent if $\Pr(A\ \&\ B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B)$.  Three events $A,B,C$ are _pairwise_ independent if $A,B$ are independent and $A,C$ are independent and $B,C$ are independent.  A sum being equal to $1$ has nothing to do with this. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I finally get it. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Write down a $6\times 6$ array of numbers $(i,j)$ where $1\leq i, j \leq 6$
and $i$ is the outcome on the red die and $j$ the outcome on the red die.
*Underline* all the outcomes corresponding to $A$, draw circles around
all outcomes corresponding to $B$, and draw square boxes around all outcomes
corresponding to $C$.  Then, *count* outcomes that are underlined/circled/boxed to find $P(A), P(B), P(C)$. You should also count outcomes
to determine $P(A\cap B), P(A\cap C), P(B\cap C)$ and
$P(A\cap B\cap C)$.

If $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B), P(A\cap C) = P(A)P(C), P(B\cap C) = P(B)P(C)$,
*and* $P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$, the events are mutually independent.

If the first three equations hold, but not the fourth, then
$A,B,C$ are *pairwise* independent but *not* mutually independent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You have an extra `$` at the end of the first paragraph. The array corresponds to both the red and blue die? I thought it meant you roll a blue die, for example, and it lands on 1 or 2. So why is it an array? If I write down `(1, 1) (1,2) (1, 3) etc..`, doesn't that mean I'm rolling the dices at the same time? How can any of them correspond to A or B at that point? Sorry, I don't quite understand. I thought `A` would be like `A = {1,2,3r,4r,5r,6}` and similar for `B`.